# Cómo le pongo el cero a la fecha obtenida

Tags: javascript

Estoy obteniendo la fecha pero cuando el día o el mes empieza con cero no lo cuenta... Qué puedo hacer para que muestre también el cero y poder usar esta fecha en un input date?

```js
let fecha = new Date();

let fecha_reverse = fecha.toLocaleDateString();


console.log(fecha_reverse);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mirando la [**documentación**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), `toLocaleDateString` lleva parámetros para que les ajustes ciertas opciones de formato:

```
toLocaleDateString(undefined, opciones)
```

Y los ajustes que tú necesitas son que tomen los ceros a la izquierda en las fechas. Entonces, guiándome de las respuestas de esta [**pregunta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040515/how-do-i-get-month-and-date-of-javascript-in-2-digit-format), puedes configurarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
let opciones = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
```

y esa variable lo envías como segundo parámetro de `toLocaleDateString`. Código:

```js
let fecha = new Date();
let opciones = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
let fecha_reverse = fecha.toLocaleDateString(undefined, opciones);

console.log(fecha_reverse);
```

Y para que lo uses en un input tipo `date`, recuerda que tu fecha debe estar en formato ISO (`YYYY-MM-DD`), entonces hacemos esto:

```
let fecha_iso = fecha_reverse.replace(/\//g, '-').split('-').reverse().join('-');
```

Aquí solo reemplazo todos los `/` por `-`, luego uso al `-` como separador (obteniendo el día, mes y año), luego invierto el array (obteniendo el año, mes y día) y esos tres los uno con `-` nuevamente, devolviéndome la cadena con el formato correcto y así ponerlo en tu input.

---

Para que lo entiendas mejor, imagina que tu fecha es `23/03/2023`, entonces:

```
fecha_reverse.replace(/\//g, '-') // reemplazo los "/" por "-" y me devuelve "23-03-2023"
fecha_reverse.replace(/\//g, '-').split('-') // me devuelve el array -> "["23","03","2023"]
fecha_reverse.replace(/\//g, '-').split('-').reverse() // me devuelve el mismo array pero invertido -> ["2023","03","23"]
fecha_reverse.replace(/\//g, '-').split('-').reverse().join('-') // junto el array con guiones -> "2023-03-23"
```

Código final:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("mi_fecha");
let fecha = new Date();
let opciones = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
let fecha_reverse = fecha.toLocaleDateString(undefined, opciones);
let fecha_iso = fecha_reverse.replace(/\//g, '-').split('-').reverse().join('-');

input.value = fecha_iso;
console.log(fecha_reverse);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="mi_fecha">
```